# Fractured line drawing in LaTeX

Tags: formatting

whenever i try and draw a slanted vector or a line in the picture environment, I get this broken line output. Does anyone know how to fix this? [image: broken line]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5):

By default latex makes sloping lines by positioning lots of small characters, and you can get artifacts like this (and which also explains the strange restrictions on the available slopes)

If you use the `pict2e` package the `picture` environment commands are redefined to instead use back end drawing primitives (typically literal pdf or postscript specials) so much smoother shapes with less restrictions on slopes and sizes are possible.

Answer (score 3):

As PDF is a vector format, I believe that this is an artifact of the PDF viewer that you use. The MWE below produces:

[image]

and zoomed in even at 2000% we the line quality is good:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-latex]
    \foreach \x in {1,4,...,40} {
        \draw[thin,blue] (0,0) -- (\x:2);
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,4,...,40} {
        \draw[ultra thin,red] (0,0) -- (-\x:2);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The question though is about picture mode not tikz, and by default that doesn't use line drawing but super-imposed glyphs from fonts with slope line segments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Granted, but then this provides an alternate solution and a reason to _not_ use `picture` mode. :-)

Comment: I get all my tikz points with picture mode answers, so I suppose this is fair enough:(